# How to invoke programmatically edit mode for TabBar?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I would like to show programmatically reorder view for TabBar, which is shown after going to 'More' tab and clicking on 'Edit' button.

Is this option available if there are less than 6 tabs? I would like to provide reorder functionality, even if 'More' tab is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no, this is not possible using the standard `UITabBarController`-provided API.

`UITabBarController` exposes a `moreNavigationController`, but not the editing view. You can't actually use the `moreNavigationController` if the tab bar controller did not decide to show it (selecting it results in an exception, presenting it results in a non-working controller being shown).

You can, however, re-create a re-ordering view using an UITableView and then update the list of controllers of your tab bar controller.

Comment: This provides a little bit more, for example you can drag icons on TabBar or from the edit view to TabBar. Is there any easy way to recreate this behaviour, at least dragging inside the TabBar?

Comment: I fear you'll have to re-create your own tab bar (and possibly controller) to do so. Or maybe one of the many UITabBarController alternatives already implements it.